# Android Wear: How to Start/Stop Heart Rate Sensor?

Tags: android, wear-os, sensors, heartbeat

I am reading heart rate of a user using Optical heart rate Sensor in the device by using `SensorEventListener

My Service is registering to listen to the event through:

```
sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

I want to unregister the listener, basically stop the heart rate sensor to save battery when the device is not in touch with a user.

How to go about implementing the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SensorManager.unregisterListener(SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor)`, with `this` as the listener.

Comment: I understand, however I only want to unregister when I am sure device is not in contact with the user, and register back when device comes in contact with user.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with sensors. Try this line inside onPause() method

```
mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
```

and you can use a flag Set it to 'false' when you want to stop getting values from sensors.

```
boolean msensor = false;
```

The sensors are registered in OnCreate or asynchronous task and you can override onSensorChanged() method for detecting any changes

check more from this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSensor/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onAccuracyChanged` method of the [`SensorEventListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html#onAccuracyChanged(android.hardware.Sensor,%2520int)) and check for [`SENSOR_STATUS_NO_CONTACT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager#SENSOR_STATUS_NO_CONTACT).

Comment: This doesn't work. If the watch loses contact with the wrist, the sensor just stops sending events.